# Two domain components of objectClass top

Tags: ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

New to LDAP. Exported the DIT as an LDIF from Apache Studio. Tried to import the LDIF file. Error occurs:

```
...
#!ERROR [LDAP: error code 32 - Unable to add entry 'dc=example,dc=com' because its parent entry 'dc=com' does not exist in the server.]
dn: dc=example,dc=com
changetype: add
dc: example
objectClass: domain
objectClass: top
```

The LDAP server is UnboundID LDAP SDK for Java 3.2.0.

I don't know enough LDAP to fix it.

Should Apache Studio have created `dc=com` before this entry?

Comment: Where do you want to import this to? What is your server? In general, You don't have a suffix or backend defined with dc=example,dc=com.

Comment: Two things I found out. The LDIF file didn't actually include the 'add' action to create entries, which I thought was odd. Second, if I added 'dc=com' at the top of the file, then I got an error that it's parent, null, did not exist. However, if I created 'dc-com' by other means, I wouldn't get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LDIF export does not guarentee ordering. LDIF import assumes ordering.

So to answer your question, yes, you should have created dc=com first.

There is a subtle exception where you can have a dc=example.com as a single node which looks confusing. But periods are legal in a name.